# SQL Server ID reseed after deleltion of a middle record

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

i have a Table from which i delete records .
The problem is when i delete a certain record,its ID flies away too, so the ID order is no longer respected within the table.
What i want  is a SQL Server Procedure to rearrange records after the deletion of one of them.

Example :

```
ID                                              ID                     ID
1                                                1                      1
2  I delete record 2, i want to have this ===>   2  and NOT this :      3
3                                                3                      4
4                                                4                      5
5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want to do this.  The `id` should be a field that has no meaning other than identifying a row.  You might have other tables that refer to the `id` and they would break.

Instead, just recalculate a sequential value when you query the table:

```
select t.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
from t;
```

Comment: Ok that solves my problem, thank you!
you're right about not changing Id, bad idea! in fact i only need that to display it ordered in a webpage, so your procedure would definetly do the trick.